# How to make a custom button export a list item to PDF using a Template and save it on Document Library

Tags: document-library, export, pdf, template

Hello and Merry Christmas !!

So on my edit item page, **I want to add a button that creates a PDF file and saves it on a Document Library, using a Template** (different than the InfoPath tempalte I'm using).

Does anyone has any Idea on how to perform this ? 
I searched on the internet, and only found how to convert to Word and print..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and Merry Christmas too !

There is a lot of solution and way to do it. (Full DEV, Workflow, custom forms ....).

It depend of your skill ;)

- You can do that with a **Workflow** (created with SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio). But here the complicated task is to generate the PDF (i recommend to use Word Automation Service)
- You can **DEV** it. Use Visual Studio to create a dev solution for SharePoint.

Here are some ideas to implement your DEV solution:

For a Button :

- Create a **Custom Action** (for adding a new button to the ribbon of your Edit form, when you click on it, it call an applicationPage (with custom logic on the Page_Load) or execute some JavaScript whitch call sharepoint REST API)

OR

- Create a **custom Form** (an application page witch is defined as form of your list or Content type) and add you asp:button with code behind logic.

How to generate PDF file :

- use **Word Automation Service** programmatically to generate your PDF

OR

- Use extra DLL like : **itextsharp**

ps: Word Automation Service, is a sharepoint service, you can add it in Central Admin. You can convert word document in other format (like PDF)

Here some links to help you :

[Create a Workflow to Archive Documents Using Word Automation Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394608(v=office.14).aspx)

[Convert Word file to PDF with REST and Word Automation Services](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Convert-1e0578a1)

[Using Word Automation Services in a Workflow custom activity for SP Designer Workflows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandru/2010/09/03/using-word-automation-services-in-a-workflow-custom-activity-for-sp-designer-workflows/)

[Converting Word Documents to PDF using Word Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff181518(v=office.14).aspx)

[What you should know about Word Automation Services](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/04/what-you-should-know-about-word-automation-services-in-sharepoint-to-convert-word-to-pdf/)

[Create Simple PDF File Using iTextSharp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d40a40/create-simple-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-library/)

Comment: Here an exemple (for SharePoint 2007 but it's almost the same in 2010 or 2013) with custom action in the ribbon and application page with custom code in the Page_Load : [SharePoint: Print Friendly Button on a List Item](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20100811-0741)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
I'm gonna try to make a workflow that does all the work at once.. I'll combine some of these solution you kindly gave me !! (I just started SharePoint, that's why I didn't know how to do so..)